# MySQL service will not start on Fedora 17

Tags: linux, fedora, mysql

I've recently installed Fedora 17 on my laptop, and I have tried several times to start the MySQL (mysqld) service on it but it refuses to do so. It gives the following error:

> [root@blackbird2 michael]# service mysqld start 
> Redirecting to
>   /bin/systemctl start  mysqld.service 
> Failed to issue method call: Unit
>   mysqld.service failed to load: No such file or directory. See system
>   logs and 'systemctl status mysqld.service' for details.

But, when I go to reinstall MySQL with the `yum install mysql` command, I get this error:

> Package mysql-5.5.25a-1.fc17.x86_64 already installed and latest
>   version

I'm not entirely sure what's going on. I installed Fedora 17 on my PC at the same time as the laptop, and MySQL seems to work fine for that. Has anyone any ideas?

Comment: If its an option, have you tried uninstalling MYSQL completely and reinstalling?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `mysql` rpm only includes client & libraries, but not the server `mysqld`. Try installing the server with...

```
# yum install mysql-server
```

MySQL-server my not be apart of your enabled repos. [Here's a guide](http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/install-mysql-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/)

Comment: Thanks that's fixed it, but I'm getting a weird thing happen now. When I tell it to start the service it will say "Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start  mysqld.service", do nothing, and then display the prompt. It still works, it's just I'm used to it saying "Starting mysqld [OK]". Any ideas?

Comment: @mickburkejnr That's just the way it works now.

Comment: I believe that `service ACTION NAMED` is aliased to `systemctl ACTION NAMED.service`, and the redirect notice is a helpful hint about the change. You'll need to do additional MySQL post-install set-up before the "Starting mysqld ... [OK]" will be displayed.

Comment: That's fine, I'm happy as long as it works. Thanks again!